# How to create a custom JupyterLab css theme extension?

Tags: themes, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I'm looking for a straight forward way to apply custom CSS to the Jupyter Lab notebook.  I've tried following the documentation and am getting the following error:

```
Missing extension module "lib/index.js"
```

after running `jupyter labextension install .`

Jupyter Lab relies on the [Themes](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/latest/developer/extension_dev.html#themes) to adjust the notebook formatting.  This seems like a reasonable way of making custom themes reusable, but I'm having a heck of a time figuring out how to make and apply the set of changes I'd like to make.

Following the documentation for Themes linked above:

> To quickly create a theme based on the JupyterLab Light Theme, follow
>   the instructions in the contributing guide and then run jlpm run
>   create:theme from the repository root directory. Once you select a
>   name, title and a description, a new theme folder will be created in
>   the current directory. You can move that new folder to a location of
>   your choice, and start making desired changes.

The steps in the [contributing guide](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/blob/d9bbf0822be5309d063249da6776e640dba7984c/CONTRIBUTING.md#setting-up-a-development-environment) led me to do the following:

1. Cloned the JupyterLab repo from GitHub using [Fork](https://git-fork.com).
2. `pip install -e .`
3. `jlpm install`
4. `jlpm run build`
5. `jlpm run build:core`
6. `jupyter lab build`

All from my local directory where I cloned the repo.  This had the side effect of installing the latest alpha build of JupyterLab, which isn't what I want.  I need to be using a stable release so I uninstalled jupyterlab through conda, and then reinstalled it.

I then repeated the above using the 0.35.4 tag of JupyterLab.  I only mention this in unlikely event that the double install screwed things up somewhere.

Then, looking at the theme [authoring documentation](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/latest/developer/extension_dev.html#extension-authoring), I first:

1. `npm install`, which runs without incident
2. `npm run build`, which complains about that `../application/tsconfig.json` isn't found which I think is ok because I don't think I'm using any TypeScript (??)
3. `jupyter labextension install .` which fails because `lib/index.js` isn't found.

I presume this is because `lib/index.js` is listed under `"main"`.

I'm not sure what parts of this config to change and what to leave the same if my only goal is to change the .css files in the `style` directory.

Here's my full `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "FirstTheme",
  "version": "0.19.1",
  "description": "My first Theme",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues"
  },
  "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
  "author": "Project Jupyter",
  "files": [
    "lib/*.d.ts",
    "lib/*.js.map",
    "lib/*.js",
    "static/*.css",
    "static/*.ttf",
    "static/*.eot",
    "static/*.woff",
    "static/*.woff2"
  ],
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "types": "lib/index.d.ts",
  "directories": {
    "lib": "lib/"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab.git"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc -b",
    "build:src": "tsc -b src",
    "build:webpack": "webpack",
    "clean": "rimraf lib && rimraf static",
    "prepublishOnly": "npm run build",
    "watch": "tsc -b --watch",
    "watch:src": "tsc -b src --watch",
    "watch:webpack": "webpack --watch"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@jupyterlab/application": "^0.19.1",
    "@jupyterlab/apputils": "^0.19.1",
    "ajv": "^6.7.0",
    "font-awesome": "~4.7.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "~0.28.7",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.4.0",
    "npm-run-all": "~4.1.1",
    "rimraf": "~2.6.2",
    "svg-url-loader": "~2.3.1",
    "svgo": "~1.0.4",
    "svgo-loader": "~2.1.0",
    "typedoc": "~0.12.0",
    "typescript": "~3.1.1",
    "url-loader": "~1.0.1",
    "webpack": "~4.12.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.0.3"
  },
  "publishConfig": {
    "access": "public"
  },
  "jupyterlab": {
    "extension": true,
    "themeDir": "static"
  }
}
```